# Create extra/custom map marker values

Tags: android, google-maps, hashmap, google-maps-markers

I was looking for a solution to my problem, i found some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333971/get-other-values-from-marker) but i couldn't make it work with my code.

So, i have a google map with markers. The markers are created with JSON information. What i want is to attach a custom value to each marker, so each time a user touches the `infowindow`, a new activity will open with passed parameters attached to the specific marker.

Here is the JSON parsing and marker creation:

```
 try{
               JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
               for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String image = jObject.getString("image");
                        String title = jObject.getString("title");
                        String snipet = jObject.getString("snipet");

                        double lat=jObject.getDouble("lat");
                        double lng=jObject.getDouble("lng");

                        addMarkers(lat, lng,image,title,snipet);
                    } // End Loop
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
                } // catch (JSONException e)

 private void addMarkers( double jLat, double jLng, final String image, final String jTitle,final String jDescription)
    {
     LatLng jLocation = new LatLng(jLat, jLng);

     alertMarkers = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(jLocation)
                    .title(jTitle)
                    .snippet(jDescription)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icon)));
      theMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, arg0.getId(), 1000).show();
    }}

    }
```

How can assign that extra parameter, i.e image,to the marker so when a user touches the marker, the corresponding image will be used for further processing.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here what i added to the code above,but something is not right:
Declared at start

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> extraMarkerInfo = new HashMap<String, HashMap>();
```

then added a new HashMap:

```
*alertMarkers = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(jLocation)
                        .title(jTitle)
                        .snippet(jDescription)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icon)));*

HashMap<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
data.put("id",alertID);
extraMarkerInfo.put(alertMarkers.getId(),data);

 public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                HashMap<String, String> marker_data = extraMarkerInfo.get(arg0.getId());
                Log.i("test",marker_data.get("id"));
(…)
```

But i am getting an error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

at line:

```
            HashMap<String, String> marker_data = extraMarkerInfo.get(arg0.getId());
```

I am bit confused with HashMaps.

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain your own `HashMap<>`, mapping [the ID value of the `Marker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getId%28%29) (generated by the system, immutable) to its corresponding extra data. Then, on a marker tap, you look up the extra data. You can see this in action in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Models).

Or, you can shove the string representation of the data (JSON) into the snippet of the `Marker`, and retrieve it again later on as needed. This will be more overhead, I suspect.

`Marker`, however, is `final` and cannot be extended.

Comment: ok,thanks for the info, i am looking at the sample project right now.