# Try to get right content for Linearlayout from JSON but get every time same content

Tags: android, json, parsing

I try to add a kind of a "preview" for my Map Activity. In this activity should be displayed the name and later the address (which is set in the json) of the marker. Unfortunately i didnt get the right content for the selected marker. I just get the content of one of the items. Here is my code:

```
   public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback



@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
   contactList = new ArrayList<>();
   SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map3);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ImageButton locations = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnloc);
    locations.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Locations.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}



private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();


        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");


                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String street = c.getString("street");
                    String postalcode = c.getString("postalcode");
                    String musicstyle = c.getString("musicstyle");
                    String musicsecond = c.getString("musicsecond");
                    String entry = c.getString("entry");
                    String opening = c.getString("opening");
                    String agegroup = c.getString("agegroup");
                    String imageurl = c.getString("imageurl");
                    String urlbtn = c.getString("urlbtn");
                    String Fsk = c.getString("Fsk");
                    String city = c.getString("city");
                    String lat = c.getString("lat");
                    String lng = c.getString("lng");




                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("street",street);
                    contact.put("postalcode",postalcode);
                    contact.put("musicstyle",musicstyle);
                    contact.put("musicsecond",musicsecond);
                    contact.put("entry",entry);
                    contact.put("opening",opening);
                    contact.put("agegroup",agegroup);
                    contact.put("imageurl",imageurl);
                    contact.put("urlbtn",urlbtn);
                    contact.put("Fsk",Fsk);
                    contact.put("city",city);
                    contact.put("lat", lat);
                    contact.put("lng", lng);

                    latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat); longitude = Double.parseDouble(lng);
                    contactList.add(contact);
                    namec = lat;
                    Imageurl = imageurl;


                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        for (final HashMap<String, String> contact: contactList) {

            LatLng P1 = new LatLng(
                        Double.parseDouble(contact.get("lat")),
                    Double.parseDouble(contact.get("lng")));

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P1).title(contact.get("name")));
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                    LinearLayout prev = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
                    prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    TextView nameprev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namepre);

                    nameprev.setText(contact.get("name"));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),contact.get("name"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;


                }
            });

            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    LinearLayout prev = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
                    prev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    TextView nameprev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namepre);
                    nameprev.setText("Clubname");
                }
            });

        }
    }


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    new GetContacts().execute();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);




}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `setOnMarkerClickListener` inside of your loop. Because this is a setter for the whole map, it overwrites the listener each time. So, I expect you always see the information of the **last** contact. Instead, you should only call this method **once**. So **not** in your for loop.

Now, you'll notice that you don't have access to your contact object. You'll have to use the marker that's passed to the click event to select the correct contact. You've set the title of the markers to the contact's name, so you should be able to pull that out of the marker and use it to find the right contact.

Something like:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                String name = marker.getTitle();
                HashMap<String, String> currContact = contactList.stream().filter(c -> c.get("name").equals(name)).findFirst().get();
                LinearLayout prev = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
                prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TextView nameprev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namepre);

                nameprev.setText(currContact.get("name"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),currContact.get("name"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;


            }
        });
```

It would probably be even simpler if you save a reference to the whole contact in the Marker's tag.

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P1).title(contact.get("name")));
marker.setTag(contact);
```

Then in the event you should be able to pull the whole object out instead of just the name:

```
HashMap<String, String> currContact = (HashMap<>) marker.getTag();
```

Comment: Doesnt work, because behind the marker are more than just the name which i need to parse into my Linearlayout so that was just an example. I have to parse more than just this things.

Comment: And if i try to set a tag how can i pull the content out of the tag?

Comment: i solved it using the following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333971/get-other-values-from-marker

Comment: @DominikHartl Everywhere I wrote `currContact` it refers to an entire contact, so you have acces to all of the contact's information not just the name. And my last code example show's you how to get the contact from the Tag. Glad you solved it!

Comment: the problem was i understood it not at first so i have to try it a few times and now its working thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Add  `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener()` and `mMap.setOnMapClickListener()` to `onCreate()` method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ................
        .........................

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                LinearLayout prev = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
                prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TextView nameprev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namepre);

                nameprev.setText(contact.get("name"));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),contact.get("name"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;


            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                LinearLayout prev = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
                prev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                TextView nameprev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namepre);
                nameprev.setText("Clubname");
            }
        });
    }
```

Update `onPostExecute()` as below:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    for (final HashMap<String, String> contact: contactList) {

        LatLng P1 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(contact.get("lat")),
                               Double.parseDouble(contact.get("lng")));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P1).title(contact.get("name")));

    }
}
```

Comment: doesnt work, because i get the Json data later than the onCreate it wants :(